# How can I sign an android app with a value that I want?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, web-applications, intel-xdk

I'm trying to upload and app to Play Store. I built the app in HTML5 and It was compiled with Cordova, using Intel XDK. When I try to upload the app to Google, I got a message like: "The certificate (digital sign) of past application are different of new".
The older app is an Android WebView, compiled using the IDE: Eclipse.
How can I sign an android app with the same value of older application?

Comment: You need the certificate you used to sign the old app.  If you have that, use it to sign the new apk.  If you don't have it-  you're screwed.

Comment: But, How can I do that? Using the same: IDE, computer, compiler...?
How can I use the same certificate for the new app in HTML5 compiled with Cordova (using Intel XDK)?

Comment: Grab the cert from the original.  If you didn't create one explicitly, you used the debug keystore found at $HOME/.android/debug.keystore.  Then worst case you can always sign it with jarsigner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign the app using the same certificate you used the first time you uploaded to Google.

Typically, when you generate the signed APK, you have to select a keystore path (or generate a new one), in your case you need to select the same one you used before. i.e. `<your_app>.jks`

If you no longer have this keystore then you cannot upload a new .apk, your only solution would be to unpublish your currently uploaded app and create a new one with your new signed .apk

If you do have your old keystore, but cannot remember the information within it, you can Google the commands to retrieve data from the keystore, (based on your OS).

Comment: Note: I've never used Cordova, so I dont know the specific generating/signing process, but it is usually fairly simple

Comment: I don't want to lose the downloads, but I will have to.